# CORS issue while hitting Azure AD's ROPC endpoint from React Application

Tags: azure, authentication, oauth, azure-active-directory, ropc

My end goal is to authenticate a AD user with his/her username and password credentials only, After research, got to know about ROPC flow, so I created an App Registration, used its tenantID, clientID and such parameters and hit the API with username and password in PostMan. I was successful in getting the tokens. Great.

I need to hit this API from my web application and get tokens.(Getting token is not my objective, but to just authenticate a user). When I try to hit this URL from my React Client, I get CORS error.

What should I do to solve this issue?

I created an App Service, but helpless, couldn't get understanding of what's happening

Answer (score 1):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the below results:***

I generated access token via ROPC Flow using below Parameters:

```json
GET https://login.microsoftonline.com/2f2ebbbc-e970-470e-8ec5-XXXXXXX/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:3e3643c5-90af-4af6-af90-XXXXX
client_secret:Client_Secret
grant_type:password
username:user@XXX.onmicrosoft.com
password:*****
scope:scope
```

[image]

To resolve the **`CORS`** error, try adding **`<allowed-headers>`** tag defined in your **`CORS`** policy:

```xml
    <cors>
        <allowed-origins>
            <origin>*/</origin>
        </allowed-origins>
        <allowed-methods preflight-result-max-age="300">
            <method>GET</method>
            <method>POST</method>
        </allowed-methods>
        <allowed-headers>
            <header>Authorization</header>
        </allowed-headers>
    </cors>
```

- Check whether you are passing wrong token and check whether you are authorized to perform the action.
- If still the issue persists, try not exposing the **`client_secret`** and call the Api.

**Reference:**

[Enable Cross-Origin Requests (CORS)  | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Comment: Thanks @Rukmini, for your response, Currently I am using React Client to hit the Auth API, so where do I have to add <allowed-headers> tag?

I just have my App Registration from where I got the clientID and tenantID, apart from that I haven't configured anything in my azure portal.